# Restrict access to my docker dev environment within the local network

Tags: security, docker

I’m using Docker for Mac for my development environment.

The problem is that anybody within our local network can access the server and the MySQL database running on my machine. Of course, they need to know the credentials, which they can possibly brute force.

For example, if my local IP is `10.10.100.22`, somebody can access my local site by typing `https://10.10.100.22:8300`, or database `mysql -h 10.10.100.22 -P 8301 -u root -p` (port `8300` maps to docker `443`, port `8301` maps to docker `3306`).

Currently, I use Mac firewall and block incoming connections for `vpnkit`, which is used by Docker. It works, but I'm not sure if this is the best approach.

**UPDATE**

The problem with firewall is that you have to coordinate it with all developers in your team. I was hoping to achieve my goal just using Docker configuration same as private networks in Vagrant https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/networking/private_network.html.

**What is the best way to restrict access to my docker dev environment within the local network?**

Comment: On linux i would use iptables for this, but with osx it should be fine to restrict access via firewall.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found very simple solution for my problem. In the `docker-compose.yml` instead of,

```
services:
    mysql:
      image: mysql:5.6
      environment:
        - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=
        - MYSQL_DATABASE=test
      ports:
         - "8301:3306"
```

which opens the `8301` port wide open for the local network. I did the following,

```
services:
    mysql:
      image: mysql:5.6
      environment:
        - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=
        - MYSQL_DATABASE=test
      ports:
         - "127.0.0.1:8301:3306"
```

which binds the `8301` port to the docker host `127.0.0.1` only and the port is not accessible outside of the host.